# ARIMA model selection for Financial data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit arima models on financial data, but I get an error:

> Error in arima(spReturnsOffset, order = c(p, d, q)) : non-stationary
>   AR part from CSS

for the following code:

```
library(quantmod)


getSymbols("^GSPC", from="1950-01-01")
spReturns = diff(log(Cl(GSPC)))
#differenced logarithmic returns of the "Closing Price" of the S&P500 and strip out the initial NA value:
spReturns[as.character(head(index(Cl(GSPC)),1))] = 0

# Create the forecasts vector to store the predictions
windowLength = 500
foreLength = length(spReturns) - windowLength
forecasts <- vector(mode="character", length=foreLength)

for (f in 0:foreLength) {
    # Obtain the S&P500 rolling window for this day
    spReturnsOffset<- spReturns[(1+f):(windowLength+f)]


order.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 4 * 4)
aic.vec <- numeric(4 * 4)
k <- 1
for (p in 1:4) for (q in 1:4) {
  order.matrix[, k] <- c(p,0,q)
  aic.vec[k] <- AIC(arima(spReturnsOffset, order=c(p, 0, q)))
  k <- k+1
  }
ind <- order(aic.vec, decreasing = FALSE)
aic.vec <- aic.vec[ind]
order.matrix <- order.matrix[, ind]
rownames(order.matrix) <- c("p", "d", "q")
order.matrix <- t(order.matrix)
result <- cbind(order.matrix, aic.vec)
colnames(result) <- c("p", "d", "q", "AIC")
}
```

I've tried MLE method in arima function as well, still I get an error msg:

> Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : Lapack routine
>   dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

I also tried using trycatch!And the code kept running!

how can I fix this?

**In response to comment by Hack-R**

The following code does work:

```
# Obtain the S&P500 returns and truncate the NA value
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="1950-01-01")
spReturns = diff(log(Cl(GSPC)))
spReturns[as.character(head(index(Cl(GSPC)),1))] = 0

# Create the forecasts vector to store the predictions
windowLength = 500
foreLength = length(spReturns) - windowLength
forecasts <- vector(mode="character", length=foreLength)

for (d in 0:foreLength) {
    # Obtain the S&P500 rolling window for this day
    spReturnsOffset = spReturns[(1+d):(windowLength+d)]

    # Fit the ARIMA model
    final.aic <- Inf
    final.order <- c(0,0,0)
    for (p in 0:5) for (q in 0:5) {
        if ( p == 0 && q == 0) {
            next
        }

        arimaFit = tryCatch( arima(spReturnsOffset, order=c(p, 0, q)),
                             error=function( err ) FALSE,
                             warning=function( err ) FALSE )

        if( !is.logical( arimaFit ) ) {
            current.aic <- AIC(arimaFit)
            if (current.aic < final.aic) {
                final.aic <- current.aic
                final.order <- c(p, 0, q)
                final.arima <- arima(spReturnsOffset, order=final.order)
            }
        } else {
            next
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may be relevant http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56794/system-is-exactly-singular-in-r-function-boxcox-ar  The comments mention some possible transformations I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I was asking, thank you for reading and suggesting.

```
#Get S&P 500
getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "2000-01-01")

#Compute the daily returns 
gspcRet<-diff(log(Cl(GSPC)))

#Use only the last two years of returns 
gspcTail<-as.ts(tail(gspcRet,500))

#Searching for the best models
order.matrix<-matrix(0,nrow = 3, ncol = 6 * 6)
aic.vec<- numeric(6 * 6)
k<-1
for(p in 0:5) for(q in 0:5){
    order.matrix[,k]<-c(p,0,q)
    aic.vec[k]<- AIC(arima(gspcTail, order=c(p,0,q)))
    k<-k+1
}
ind<- order(aic.vec,decreasing=F)
aic.vec<- aic.vec[ind]
order.matrix<- order.matrix[,ind]
order.matrix<- t(order.matrix)
result<- cbind(order.matrix,aic.vec)
colnames(result)<- c("p","d","q","AIC")
```